# SQLiteOpenHelper returns getDatabaseLocked

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to access an SQLite value from Firebase database helper class. My code returns an error :

> Android Database Sqlite SQLiteOpenHelper getDatabaseLocked

```
private Context mContext;

public BookFirebaseHelper() {

    BididDB db = new BididDB(mContext);
    db.open();
    String ref=db.getData();
    db.close();

    mDataBase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReferenceBooks=mDataBase.getReference("myconnectionref").child(ref);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `mContext` you're passing to `BididDB` constructor is `null`. There's an `SQLiteOpenHelper` somewhere there and giving its constructor a null for a `Context` results in a crash in `getDatabaseLocked()`.

Comment: Use a valid `Context`. Where to obtain one depends on your... context. `Application` or `Activity` are typical `Context`s you'd use.

Comment: does this context refers from BididDB class?

Answer (score 0):

You have not made your class a DB Helper?

```
public BookFirebaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper() {
    // your code here...
}
```